# ASP Session Cookies Removal

Tags: asp.net, httponly

Using the following web.config file properties I am not able to have my site either remove a session cookie or force the cookie to use HTTPOnly. I am using a basic classic asp website with the below configuration in my web.config file

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
  <httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true" />
  <sessionState mode="Off" cookieless="true"/>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

I have tried to use the following outbound rule to rewrite the URL however when the site gets scanned using Qualys it does not rewrite the cookie before the website is scanned. Here is the below property code that is not working:

```
 <outboundRules>
    <rule name="Add HttpOnly" preCondition="No HttpOnly">
        <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Set_Cookie" pattern=".*" negate="false" />
        <action type="Rewrite" value="{R:0}; HttpOnly" />
        <conditions>
        </conditions>
    </rule>
    <preConditions>
        <preCondition name="No HttpOnly">
            <add input="{RESPONSE_Set_Cookie}" pattern="." />
            <add input="{RESPONSE_Set_Cookie}" pattern="; HttpOnly" negate="true" />
        </preCondition>
    </preConditions>
</outboundRules>
```

Comment: Try to skip `cookieless` property: `<sessionState mode="Off"/>` It doesn't work too? (When testing please remove that outbound rule.) Also what version of `asp.net` you are using?

Comment: You have set `mode="Off"` on `SessionState`. No Asp.Net session cookie should be generated. Are you mixing up/confused about the many different meanings of the term `session cookie`? With the question in its current state, it is difficult to know what exactly your problem is...

Comment: I am using version: 4.0.30319.42000

Comment: Yes, sessionState is off but a session cookie is still being generated.

Comment: And I still have the cookie generated even without `cookieless`.

Comment: This is a "classic ASP website" or asp.net? Looks like .net. If so, *please* update your question to say ASP.NET.

Comment: This is a Classic ASP website.

Answer (score 2):

You could always ask the client to 'kill' the cookie (with code attached below) and hope it does so. If this doesn't happen, it could be that there is a bug on the client side or that a user has copied the cookie out of the browser before the expiration, and copies it back in. Anyway... If you can't find a fix, the workaround would be to kill the cookie **EVERYTIME** you use it.

```
HttpCookie cookieToKill= new HttpCookie(cookieName);
cookieToKill.Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-1); //any negative value will do)
Response.Cookies.Add(cookieToKill);
```

Comment: This was it! I had loaded the document cookies after I edited them. Thanks!